# Kendo Grid is not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui

I am having trouble starting with kendo grid with asp.net mvc 4. I have controller method which is passing data to view which works fine but I am trying to view in kendo grid. I have add reference through ManageNuGet.

here is my code

```
 public ActionResult createNewStore()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult createNewStore(Store storeModel)
    {
          var db = new AppContext();

           var Store = new Store { address = storeModel.address, postcode = storeModel.postcode, city = storeModel.city, Country = storeModel.Country };
           db.Stores.Add(Store);
           db.SaveChanges();

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult viewStores()
    {
        var db = new AppContext();

        var query = from b in db.Stores
                    orderby b.storeID
                    select b;

        return View(query.ToList());

    }

    public void Delete()
    {
    }
```

### View Code

```
@model IEnumerable <MyProject_04.Models.Store>

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "viewStores";
 }

 <link href="~/Content/kendo/2012.3.1114/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="~/Content/kendo/2012.3.1114/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
 <script src="~/Scripts/kendo/2012.3.1114/kendo.web.min.js"></script>


  <script type="text/javascript">

   $(function () {
     $(".delete-link").click( function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if (confirm("do you want to delete record?")) {
            $(this).closest("tr").hide("slow");
        }
        return false;
    });

           $("#grid").kendoGrid();
   });

  </script>

  <h2>View All the list of stores</h2>


   <table id="grid">
    <thead> 
     <tr>
      <th>Store ID</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>post Code</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>Action</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>

   <tbody>
     @foreach (var item in Model)
      {
        <tr>
         <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=> item.storeID)</td>
         <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=> item.address)</td>
         <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=> item.postcode)</td>
         <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=> item.city)</td>
         <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=> item.Country)</td>
         <td>@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.storeID }, new { @class ="delete-link"})</td>
          </tr>
       }
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

---

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
      <link href="~/Content/kendo/2012.3.1114/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/kendo/2012.3.1114/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">

     <!--------------Header------------------->
    <div id="header">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p class="site-title">@Html.ActionLink("MVC Movie", "Index", "Home")</p>
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>

     <!--------------Body------------------->          
  <div id="body">
      @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
      <script src="~/Scripts/kendo/2012.3.1114/kendo.web.min.js"></script>

       @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
       <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">

             @RenderBody()
       </section>


  </div>

     <!--------------Footer------------------->
   <div id="footer">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET MVC Application</p>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
   </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
 </html>
```

I have changed my default layout but it is still not working.

Comment: i believe i am not referencing kendo files right!!! i have managed to work with empty web template but still struggling with MVC pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that is a mess.  Only put your @Scripts.Render, script references, and stylesheet links inside the HEAD of your _Layout view.  Ends up MVC should look really clean and simple when you are done.

And as for the Kendo part.  I know their documentation and samples could be better, and in-fact their samples are usually the worst way to do it.  But, search this site for other examples and issues people have.  I think you might be missing the point of the Kendo Grid and need to start from scratch.  Get a simple example, make it work, then expand on it.

Good luck, and happy coding.